# How to calculate funding amount from fellowship award to list in CV?

Tags: funding, cv

Many people list the monetary funding amounts awarded from successful grants, especially PIs who apply for multiple grants.

As a young researcher/postdoc, I would like to know how to calculate the total funding amount from a fellowship, e.g., Japan Society for the Promotion of Science Postdoctoral Fellowship, etc.
These kinds of fellowships usually list a maintenance grant (salary) for the number of years the fellowship lasts for. Additionally, you can apply for funds for research. Is the total amount of funds simply these added together or is there a way to find out? The research fund part is a little bit difficult as the group I am working with essentially applies through my successful award.

Comment: Either you give the correct order of magnitude (unless the fellowship is an "obscure" one  is sufficient) or you give the exact amount as reported in the grant agreement (i.e. 112'356€ plus travel funds up to 7558.32€).
Please remember that fund-hungry head of depts and professors know the (huge) value of these fellowships, in general there is no ranking about how much money were brought in (unless that group is led by such a person...).

Answer (score 1):

In all cases I've seen (e.g. a Marie Skłodowska-Curie Individual Fellowship) the total grant amount will be listed somewhere in the grant agreement.